# Ansible Jinja error while using int|abs

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

{% set shutdown_port = (tomcat_services[current_app_name]["service_port"] +5)|int|abs %}
 I am using the above in tomcat contect.xml to get the shutdown port +5 of service port.
 when i run the playbook  "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'"

can some body help me with this error

Answer (score 1):

i tried the syntax `.... | int | abs` on ansible 2.5 and got the same error, while on ansible 2.4 it works.

i think you are affected by [this bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37856)